# Mosquitto subscriber receiving extra message

Tags: go, mqtt, mosquitto

I am exploring mosquitto as a complete beginner.  I have a golang test program that I'm using to see how it manages messages, but subsequent runs of the program show an extra message received.

```
import (
    mqtt "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)
var sent int
var received int

func Test() {
    sent  = 0
    received = 0
    const TOPIC = "mytopic/test"

    opts := mqtt.NewClientOptions().AddBroker("tcp://localhost:1883").SetClientID("client1").SetResumeSubs(false).SetAutoReconnect(false).SetCleanSession(true)

    client1 := mqtt.NewClient(opts)
    if token := client1.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        panic(token.Error())
    }
    if token := client1.Subscribe(TOPIC, 2, receiver1); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        panic(token.Error())
    }

    defer howManySent()
    defer howManyReceived()
    defer client1.Disconnect(1)

    for index:=0;index<3;index++ {
        sendMsg := "client1 message " + strconv.Itoa(index)
        if token := client1.Publish(TOPIC, 2, true, sendMsg); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
            panic(token.Error())
        } else {
            sent++
        }
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
    time.Sleep(1*time.Second)
}

func howManyReceived() {
    log.Warn("RECEIVED:", received)
}

func howManySent() {
    log.Warn("SENT:", sent)
}

func receiver1(client mqtt.Client, msg mqtt.Message) {
    received++
    msg.Ack()
    output := "message id:" + strconv.Itoa(int(msg.MessageID())) + " message = " + string(msg.Payload())
    log.Warn(output)
}
```

Output for the first run:

```
WARN[0000] message id:1 message = client1 message 0     
WARN[0001] message id:2 message = client1 message 1     
WARN[0002] message id:3 message = client1 message 2     
WARN[0004] RECEIVED:3                                   
WARN[0004] SENT:3
```

Output for the second run:

```
WARN[0000] message id:4 message = client1 message 2     
WARN[0000] message id:5 message = client1 message 0     
WARN[0001] message id:6 message = client1 message 1     
WARN[0002] message id:7 message = client1 message 2     
WARN[0004] RECEIVED:4                                   
WARN[0004] SENT:3
```

My configuration file is the default installed with mosquitto, except I turned off persistence to see if it helped:

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence false
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Publish](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang#Client) is defined as follows:

```
Publish(topic string, qos byte, retained bool, payload interface{}) Token
```

So when you call `token := client1.Publish(TOPIC, 2, true, sendMsg)` you are publishing a message with `retained` set to true. [Retain](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc385349265) is a flag passed with the message to the broker and means:

> If the RETAIN flag is set to 1, in a PUBLISH Packet sent by a Client to a Server, the Server MUST store the Application Message and its QoS, so that it can be delivered to future subscribers whose subscriptions match its topic name [MQTT-3.3.1-5]. When a new subscription is established, the last retained message, if any, on each matching topic name MUST be sent to the subscriber [MQTT-3.3.1-6].

Each new message with `retain` set replaces any previous messages so when your first execution completes message `2` is retained. This is sent to the client when it reconnects (meaning the results you are seeing are expected). If you change the call to `token := client1.Publish(TOPIC, 2, false, sendMsg)` it will act as you expect.

The [mosquitto docs](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) say the following about the `persistence` flag:

> If true, connection, subscription and message data will be written to the disk in mosquitto.db at the location dictated by persistence_location. When mosquitto is restarted, it will reload the information stored in mosquitto.db

So this only has an impact if you restart Mosquitto; session information will still be stored in memory even if this flag is set to `false`.

Comment: But the message was delivered and acked.  Why would it be stored?  Given that I have persistence configured to false and have verified that no mosquitto.db file is present ... more curiously, WHERE is it stored?  :D

Comment: I guess it's stored in memory?  But I tried restarting the server and got the same result.  Also, would this be a considered a new subscription if I'm using the same client ID?

Comment: It is stored in memory. If you have `persistence false` in `mosquitto.conf` then the first time you run your app after restarting Mosquitto you should not get the extra message. Ref the `same client ID`; you are using `SetCleanSession(true)` which tells the broker to throw away the client session when it disconnects. In any event [MQTT-3.8.4-3](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc384800440) dictates that retained messages be sent even if there is already an identical subscription.